# How to assign value of variable to radio button

Tags: php, html

My code looks like that:

```
foreach($options as $option) {

?>

<input type="radio" name="option" value=<?php $option ?>><?php echo $option?><br>


<?php }?>

<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Vasta">
</form>
```

But it does not give the result I want. How could I give radio buttons value of variable $option? This question might have to little information about problem, if it is necessary i post more of my code.

When I change `value=<?php $option ?>` to `value='dog'` everything works the way I want, the value will be given.

Comment: What is the point of placing the variable and then echoing it? Why not just value=<?php echo $option; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your `echo` statement. I also suspect you have spaces in your values which breaks your HTML because you are not using quotes around those values:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $option ?>"><?php echo $option?><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`value="<?php echo $option ?>">`